# jQuery autosuggest array styling

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, autosuggest

I use the simple jQuery autosuggest in one of my search forms, however I'm not quite sure on how I can make this easier to style.

What happens at the moment is, 
It displays the results like:

```
**name** **(age)** - **state**
John (66) - here
Jack (36) - there
Jason (46) - here
Jimmy (56) - there
```

However I want to make some sort of a table out of it with predefined widths like:

```
**name**    **(age)**    - **state**
John     (66)     - here
Jack     (36)     - there
Jason    (46)     - here
Jimmy    (56)     - there
```

Currently the array that collects the data looks like:

```
$data = array();
if ( $rs && mysql_num_rows($rs) )
{
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($rs, MYSQL_ASSOC) )
{
    $data[] = array(
        'label' => $row['name'] .'('. $row['age'] .') - '. $state,
        'value' => $row['name']
    );
}
}
echo json_encode($data);
flush();
```

Besides this bit that gathers the data here is the javascript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($)
{
$.widget('custom.custom_autocomplete', $.ui.autocomplete,
{
    _renderMenu: function(ul, items)
    {
        var self = this;
        $.each(items, function(index, item)
        {
            var li = self._renderItem(ul, item);
        });

        $(ul).addClass('sis');
    }
});

$('#sis').custom_autocomplete({
    minLength:1 ,
    source:'autocomplete.php' ,
    selectFirst:true
});
});
```

Comment: Just extend `_renderItem` and wrap name, age, and state individually in `spans`; you can set them to `display:inline-block; width: 100px;`

Comment: Any clue on how to do this exactly? I'm not all that fresh with javascript really? any examples somewhere? like do I just add ul, item, span and I can use spans?

Comment: So, I take it you didn't write the above code ^^ ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the renderItem function of autocomplete as described in the autocomplete tutorial on the jQuery website on this page: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#custom-data

You have to make a few changes in your code however:

Changing your response json with this new structure

To the following:

```
$data[] = array(
'name' => $row['name'],
'row' =>  $row['age'],
'state' => $state,
'value' => $row['name']
);
```

Next you should make changes to your Javascript code using the autocomplete _renderItem() Function

It will look like this

```
$( "#sis" ).autocomplete({
            minLength: 0,
            source: autocomplete.php,
        })
        .data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
            return $( "<li></li>" )
                .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
                .append( "<p><span class='width100'>" + item.name + "</span><span class='width100'>(" + item.age+ ")</span><span class='width100'>-" + item.state+ "</span></p>")
                .appendTo( ul );
        };
```

Finally Add the following CSS code in your CSS file to support the width

```
p.width100{
    width: 100px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    text-align: center; 
}
```

It should eventually produce the desired result. You can edit the CSS according to your needs.